# Are there free speech to text API's for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, speech, speech-to-text

I would like to create a web interface which would utilize a speech to text feature. Does anyone know of any speech to text api's which can be written in Javascript? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

There is a very new HTML5 API for this, and although chrome is the only browser supporting it it is a built in feature of HTML5, it is still awesome and accurate. I don't use it, but you can find out more about it here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly APIs available that allow you to use JavaScript in conjunction with them: http://speechapi.com/apis/javascript/